# Plot title misaligned in gnuplot for certain title strings?

Tags: gnuplot

I am recently seeing an issue, where gnuplot does not correctly align some plot titles (`set title`). For instance the sequence

```
set term pdfcairo
set output "x.pdf"
set multiplot layout 2,2
set title "V,"
plot sin(x)
plot sin(x)
plot sin(x)
plot sin(x)
```

will produce the output

[image]

where only the title of the top-left image is misaligned. Additionally, whether a title is misaligned depends heavily on the specific character sequence, with no clear pattern as to what triggers the behavior. The issue occurs without `multiplot` too, and can also occur in the middle of a larger multiplot layout. It does seem to be limited to postscript-related terminals though (e.g. `pdf`, `pdfcairo`, `eps`).

Since I need the titles to be generated automatically, I cannot fix this on an individual basis. Additionally, the behavior exists both for `gnuplot 5.2 patchlevel 2` (default of my linux system) and `gnuplot 5.2 patchlevel 8` (most recent release).

Is there any known workaround for this behavior?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with Windows, gnuplot 5.2.8. The title is centered also in the first graph. Have you maybe tried a `reset session` at the beginning? I cannot reproduce this on Ubuntu 18.04.4, gnuplot 5.2.2 as well.

Comment: @theozh Makes no difference. I was executing the script directly as `gnuplot FILENAME.plt` anyway, so it isn't surprising. My guess would be (yet another) subtle bug caused by globally shared dependencies, Linux's unresolved version of "DLL hell"...

Comment: very strange! What if you explicitely specify `set title "V," offset 0,0`? You say this behaviour depends on the specific character sequence. Can you give examples which character sequences show this behaviour and which don't? Is it time or history dependent?

Comment: @theozh It is very arbitrary. `V,`, `V-`, `v-` are all shifted by different amounts, while `v-` is not, or combinations with some other letters I tried. `V-V-` is shifted twice as much as `V-`, so the number of punctuation characters seems to play a role. I couldn't reproduce a case, where other titles than the first are shifted, that doesn't contain confidential data. And it seems to appear only with the default Sans font, at least for those character sequences; The amount depends on the font-size, and gets increasingly worse with smaller sizes below font size 10.